# What is the best way to output the mounted DOM's HTML when a React Jest test fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jest-junit

I am using jest-junit to output the contents of the failed tests into an XML file. I would like to also add a snapshot of the mounted component at time of failure to the contents of the failure. I am open to using something other than jest-junit to achieve this, but I must use jest. Thanks!